# A problem with lemma about cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

I have a small, but important for me, question about one lemma. I cannot understand one thing.

**Lemma:** Let us suppose that $G$ is a finite, abelian group which is not cyclic and for each prime $p_{i}$, $p_{i} \mid ord(G)$, $x_{i} \in G$ and $l_{i} \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $ord(x_{i}) = p_{i}^{l_{i}}$ and $l_{i}$ is maximal for $p_{i}$. THEN: There exist $N$ such that $N = p_{1}^{l_{1}} \cdot p_{2}^{l_{2}} \cdot ... \cdot p_{k}^{l_{k}} \mid ord(G), N < ord(G)$ and for each $x \in G ~~ x^{N} = 1$.

I understand, why $N < ord(G)$ but I cannot prove why for each $x \in G ~~ x^{N} = 1$. My teacher said me, that we can assume that there exist $g \in G$ such that $N_{1} = ord(g) \nmid N$. Then there exist $l \in \mathbb{N}$, that $p^{l} \mid N_{1}$ but $p^{l} \nmid N$. He claimed that it means that it is equivalent to the fact that there exist $j \in \mathbb{N}$, that $p=p_{j}$ and $l > l_{j}$ what is in conflict with the fact that $l_{j}$ is maximal for $p_{j}$. I don't understand it. Could you explain me this fact?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Just curious, why do you understand that $N<ord(G)$?

Comment: $N$ is a divisor of $ord(G)$ but is less than $ord(G)$, cannot be $N = ord(G)$.

Comment: If $|x|=p^l$ and $|y|=q^m$ (where $p\ne q$ and $l,m>0$) then $|xy|=p^lq^m$ will not be a prime power, so it looks like there should only be one prime number in play. Unless your lemma doesn't apply to all $x\in G$, but is only saying for each prime divisor $p\mid |G|$ there exists an $x\in G$ such that...?

Comment: It is not important. We assume that there exist $N$ which is a described product and $\forall x \in G ~~ x^{N} = 1$. This approach works for every element of $G$.

Comment: In your comment, you say we're assuming there is an $N$ such that $x^N=1$ for all $x\in G$, but if that's what you're assuming from the get-go then you don't have a question!

Comment: Yeah, I should write it more precisely. As a assumption is existing such described $N$. I have to prove that for such defined $N$ for every element of $G$ $x^{N} = 1$.

Comment: If your assumptions are that (a) *every* element of the group has order equal to a prime power, then your group must be a $p$-group i.e. there can only be one prime on the table. If, on the other hand, you're only assuming that (b) for every prime divisor $p$ of $|G|$ there exists an $x\in G$ and maximal exponent $l$ such that $x$ has order $p^l$, then it's different. So are you talking about (a) or are you talking about (b)? What's written sounds like (a), but it'd make more sense as a question if it were (b).

Comment: I'm talking about (b) :)

Answer (score 2):

A finite abelian group is a direct product of its Sylow subgroups, and if they were all cyclic, $G$ would also be cyclic, so one of them, say the $p$-Sylow subgroup, is non-trivial and non-cyclic.  Then if $Ord(G)=p^nq_1^{a_1}\cdot\cdot\cdot q_r^{a_r}$, set $N=p^{n-1}q_1^{a_1}\cdot\cdot\cdot q_r^{a_r}$.  This works, since the elements in the first coordinate will have order a divisor of $p^n$ but less than $p^n$ since the p-Sylow is not cyclic.

To see that a finite abelian group is cyclic if all its Sylow subgroups are cyclic, let there be $s$ factors in the representation of $G$ as a direct product of its cyclic subgroups, take the $s$-tuple containing a cyclic generator of each factor, and show that it generates $G$.

Also, note that the result is only true for abelian groups.  For example, the non-abelian group of order 21 has all Sylow subgroups cyclic, but 21 is the smallest exponent $N$ such that $x^N=1$ for all $x$ in the group.

Comment: Instead of the non-abelian group of order 21, couldn't you use the non-abelian group of order 6 ?

Comment: Indeed you can use any non-abelian finire group with cyclic Sylow subgroups.